# Операции с массивом в ассемблере

Tags: c, ассемблер, gcc

В коде на Си был объявлен массив int ivector[6].Запустив в gcc с оптимизацией -О2 увидел это

```
    movw %r9w, ivector4(%rip) 
    movw %r10w,ivector4+2(%rip) 
    movw %r11w, ivector4+4(%rip) 
    movw    %ax, ivector4+6(%rip)
    movl    $8, %eax
    movw    %ax, ivector4+8(%rip)
    movl    $10, %eax
    movw    %ax, ivector4+10(%rip)
```

Не понятно, что за действия с массивом произошли, можете объяснить?

Comment: Зачем загадки загадывать? посмотрите, какому коду C это соответствует, будет понятнее...

Comment: @Harry,в этом-то всё и дело, я не вижу там действий , которые соотносились бы с тем, что выдаёт компилятор, поэтому спрашиваю, зачем компилятору это делать, вообще очень похоже на адресную арифметику , но я не уверен

Comment: Если вы мало-мальски знакомы с ассемблером, что семантика кода - очевидна. О чем тогда *именно* вопрос?

Comment: @AnT, пытаюсь найти корни проблемы , просто gcc мне после оптимизации одного кода выдал такое  `movl $ivector5+12, %ecx
 movl $ivector5+812, %esi` и вообще не ясно, как в цикле от 0 до 100 такое вышло

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Вы разрезали код "посередине", но в общем все достаточно очевидно: код состоит из повторяющихся пар

```
movl    константа, %eax
movw    %ax, ivector4 + смещение (%rip)
```

Сначала в `ax` заносится какое-то значение, а затем оно копируется в элемент массива. То есть каждая такая пара реализует присваивание

```
ivector4[ индекс ] = константа;
```

где `индекс` соответствует вышеупомянутому `смещению`.

Comment: movl  $ivector5+12, %ecx, а если стоит доллар - значит константа , то есть берется смещение от имени-адреса и значение лежащее там ?

Comment: `$ivector5` - это константа, представляющая адрес объекта `ivector5`. "Значение лежащее там" не берется. Берется просто сумма константы `$ivector5` и константы `12` и заносится в `ecx`.

Comment: " константы $ivector5 " - это значение лежащее в нулевом месте массива ?

Comment: а это смещение чем регулируется , то есть оно будет смещаться на размер  базового типа , то есть на 4 ? Вроде не на 4 смещается , просто кусок этого кода на Си выглядит так:`for( i = 0; i <=5;i++) 
ivector4[ i ] = i * 2;` получается ,что он как бы двигается на смещение , которое должно добавляться в соответствующую  ячейку массива , это как такое возможно ?

Comment: ,Возможно, непонятно выразился.Вот мы движемся по массиву, прибавляя размер базового типа , это ведь число постоянное , в моём случае это 4 байта , так как же мы тут прибавляем 8 , потом 10 , это же значения , получаемые от i * 2, почему это вдруг они смещениями стали , а не просто значениями, вставляемые в нужное место

Comment: @Elvin: Нет, константа `$ivector5` нигде в памяти не лежит. Эта константа существует только в воображении компилятора. А то, что смещение увеличивается на 2 - так я подозреваю, что на данной платформе размер `int` равен 2. Почему вы решили, что эти значения получаются от `i * 2`? Нет, это просто так совпало из-за того, что `sizeof(int) == 2`.